# Query for compare field of each row with field of all other rows of same table?

Tags: mysql, oracle

Name- permission

```
Raj - 11 
Jann - 23 
Raj -18 
Raj -10 
Jann -45
```

Result should be name with max permission

```
Raj -18 
Jann -45
```

Can any one please suggest me how to query for this.

there are thousands of users in table not only one or two to use where condition.

Answer (score 5):

As documented under [Maximum of Column per Group](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group.html), you want to *group* your table using a suitable [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT Name, MAX(permission) FROM users GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: thanks,select  k.name, k.id,  c.ID, max(d.permissions) as  "Highest permission"  from K_table k, CHILDREN c, DT_table d where type in(0,1) and  k.ID=c.c_id and k.id=d.rightid GROUP BY k.name;

Comment: thanks, actually i have complex query for the same which uses the joins if i am trying with the below query i am getting error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. what is wrong in it?
select  k.name, k.id,  c.ID, max(d.permissions) as  "Highest permission"  from K_table k, CHILDREN c, DT_table d where type in(0,1) and  k.ID=c.c_id and k.id=d.rightid GROUP BY k.name;